# Feature class - HEC-GeoRAS

Tags: arcgis-10.3, features, floating-point, double, hec-georas

I am currently working with HEC-GeoRAS

I am trying to import data from a shapefile into the feature class River. I would like to insert a type of data DOUBLE in the attribute ARCLENGTH of the table but I do not have the option. ARCLENGTH only allows float data.

How can I solve this problem?